# How do you say "Thursday will be cloudy" in Chinese

Tags: translation, word-choice

Is it just "星期四会阴天"?

Also if you say "Thursday will be cloudy" it translates to "星期四有风”, so do you also say "星期四会有热”？

Comment: 热 is not usually used as a noun in daily speech. So not "有热".

Comment: 刮风 may be used instead of 有风

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"thursday will be cloudy" means "星期四（是）阴天" or "星期四（是）多云".

有风 means 'windy', not 'cloudy'.

We usually say "星期四（天气）（会）很热”, "星期四有风”, "星期四(是)晴天”， "星期四有雨”， "星期四（可能）（会）下雨” and etc.

Comment: Why can't 会 be used in 星期四阴天? Because it should be considered as a noun?

Comment: 星期四会是阴天? sounds better, because (as you said) it's a noun. In  星期四会阴天?， you would use 阴天 as a verb(it's ok for understanding, but a bit unnatural I think).